# How to let gradle always download the latest version of a dependency?

Tags: gradle, dependencies

We have a custom gradle plugin, which is applied to all the projects we have. Since the plugin is released every several days, I don't want to update all the codebase to change it to use the latest version of the plugin.

How to declare it in gradle to ask it always get the latest version of the dependency?

I tried:

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com:my-plugin:[1.0.0,)"
}
```

or

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com:my-plugin:+"
}
```

They can get the latest version the first time, but won't get the newer one again.

Answer (score 2):

as a default, once gradle resolved a dynamic dependency, gradle won't check for newer versions for 24h. you have different options to influence this. one option is to run your build with `--refresh-dependencies` or you customize the TTL in your build script. E.g:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 10, 'minutes'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following script should do the job:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.google.inject:guice:latest.release'
   }
}
```

Check out the docs [here](https://docs.gradle.org/1.9-rc-1/userguide/dependency_management.html).

Another option is to go for snapshot publishing and configure dependency resolver to check seconds if the library changes so often.